# Появлениие и скрытие блока при скроллинге страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

На [этом](https://gangga-development.ru/) сайте есть плавающий хэадер.
Нужно что бы при скроллинге в плавающий хеадер слева дабавлялся логотип.
Я добавил логотип в HTML блок плавающего хеадера, задал display: none; и далее использую такой скрипт:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>200){
      $('.header-bottom .site-branding a img').show()
    }else{
      $('.header-bottom .site-branding a img').hide()
    }
  });
});
```

При проктуртке вниз все в порядке. А при прокрутке вверх лого изсчезает слишком рано - какое время плавающий хэдер прокруичвается без логотипа. Не удается за место 200 подобрать нужное значение для JS скрипта.
Подскажите поажлуйса как этот можно решить.
И так же при скроллинге пригает верстка. Можно с этим что то придумать?

Comment: Добавьте больше кода в вопросу